# Strip html tags except certain tags

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to strip all the html tags but not some certain tags like a,img and h3.

I am using this code below but it's stripping every tags.

```
<.[^]*?>
```

Please use this sample below. I want to leave the a,img and h3 tags unchanged.

```
<article>
<p>Test paragraph</p>
<a href="ttt">link</a>
<figure>dadadsadsa</figure>
<img src="#">
<h3>This is a test title</h3>
</article>
```

Thanks!

Comment: This will be always subject to the HTML in play, you can regex check for matches or specific elements but many pages could be different so you'd build the checks yourself!

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. Here's the code I use to leave the other tags.

```
<(?!img|a |/a>|h3|/h3).*?>
```